# is there any way to see the access logs for azure load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, access-log

- I have a standard load balancer in azure, and some clients complain that they receive 503 error status code.
  They are accessing the load balancer service behind their local proxy server.
- I suspect the issue is on the client side (at the proxy server level), but I would like to verify the load balancer access log, just to be extra sure.
- Is there any way to see those logs?
- I've enabled the logging on Activity Log -> Diagnostics settings and checked all the logs (Administrative, Security, ServiceHealth, Alert, Recommendation, Policy, Atuoscale,Resource Health), and I can see the metrics under the Storage Account -> Metrics, but I can't manage to find any access/error logs which is what I need in order to see if the client is reaching the load balancer or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Azure Load Balancer does not have access logs. Azure Load Balancer does not provide Layer 7-based HTTP/HTTPS access logs because it operates on Layer 4. Also, 503 errors are not errors output by the load balancer. 50x, 40x, etc. are errors output by the application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview

Answer (score -2):

Connect your load balancer to Log Analytics. You can query your logs in there and create visualisations. It will automatically grab your diagnostic settings logs as well.

Here is the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log)

Comment: Thanks, I already enabled it. But I can't manage to find the access.log. I need to see which IP's are hitting my load balancer.

Comment: If you really want to view detailed information you should use a reverse proxy or some sort of application gateway. Azure load balancer does not interact with the traffic at all, it's also not designed to do that. You can also add a firewall to the application gateway if you need specific filtering rules.